Staging Ground questions listing intermittently shows fewer questions than actual
The Staging Ground's question listing page seems to have some issue currently. It takes more time to load than normal and intermittently also returns fewer questions than are actually present.
Some of the times I refreshed the page I got between 0-6 questions in the listing even though currently there seem to be around 200 questions in the Staging Ground.
Here's an image of one of the instances I got 0 questions in the result (Note I have no filters):


Note: I am currently getting 181 questions in SG but the page load is quite slow around 5 seconds.

I'm not getting the problem of seeing fewer questions than it states should be there, but the load time is poor. I get 5-5.5 seconds (or ~1/5 profile load time ;) ), and that load time isn't impacted by things like filtering on my watched tags.

For me, filters work intermittently , from 0 to hundreds of questions in my watched tags.  Normally I see about 20-30. Now, status = new,  shows 0 questions without any other filter

The loading time seems to be back to normal now and the question listing also seems to be showing the correct count.

Ok, it's back to being slow.

Thanks for flagging.  Can confirm this is slower than it should be. We had previously created a special filtered index for staging ground posts that helped speed up the listing page, but required an exact match on the Post.CreationDate > SGStartDate predicate to work and we did some refactoring that broke the ability to take advantage of the index.  We'll get out a fix for this on Monday.

Thanks for the report Abdul Aziz Barkat!  Ok, the listing page load should at least be much faster now.  We used to have a filtered index based on the exact start date, so we could search for posts after SG launch instead of over the last 16 years.  Yes, yes, I know that doesn't scale forever, but it certainly helps us today.  The issue is the filtered index relies on the exact CreationDate > StartDate match to work, and we tweaked something that broke it.
We've added it back with my new favorite technique of creating a StagingGroundFirstPostWatermarkId with something like the following query
SELECT MIN(p.Id) - 1
FROM Posts p
JOIN PostStates ps ON ps.Id = p.PostState
WHERE ps.IsStagingGround = 1

We only have to run that a single time, and then can effectively filter to only consider SG posts by making sure Post.Id > @StagingGroundFirstPostWatermarkId

I'm still not sure what might have been going on with posts not showing up at all.  Can you report back again if you see either of those two issues come up again?

The posts not showing up only happened that day and I haven't reproduced it since, so I guess it's probably fixed.

In retrospective, I think the Staging Ground being empty was me running a script that analyzed all Staging Ground posts (I was interested in comments) at that time/getting data about them without thinking about requesting question getting the review lock. If that was the case, I guess a single user getting many review locks at once shouldn't be possible.
